# Minimum version of .NET 2.0 framework to support Powershell 2.0?

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild

Background:  I had a build machine with .NET 2.0 SP1 (and no higher) which uses msbuild and powershell for its build; unfortunately, workstations cannot load the binaries built on this machine, unless .NET 2.0 SP2 is installed.

To fix this I'm creating a build machine with minimum specs; the most important one being .NET 2.0 SP1.

If I install Powershell 2.0, is there a good chance that I'm introducing dependencies on higher versions of the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in [Windows Management Framework (Windows PowerShell 2.0, WinRM 2.0, and BITS 4.0)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929/en-us)that PowerShel V2.0 is supported on Windows XP SP3. PowerShell V2 is based on .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Some features, like ISE, and the `Out-GridView` cmdlet requires .Net 3.5 SP1